# Why is GetDeb only installing FileZilla 3.15.0-1~getdeb1?

Tags: filezilla, ubuntu-16.04

when i try to install filezilla in ubuntu xenial using `sudo apt-get install filezilla` it's only installing 3.15.0 version. where problem is there is no option to configure proxy.

even when i try to upgrade using apt-get , it's showing message that filezilla at its latest version which is 3.15.0 .

so i want to install 3.21.0 version of filezilla. but when i try to install with alternate way. it's tries to use getdeb repository. which is down .

what should i do ? any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-base libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev nettle-dev autogen lintasn1-6-dev libunbound-dev libidn11-dev libidn2-dev p11-kit-dev guile-2.0-dev libtspi1-dev libelf-dev libpugixml-dev libcppunit-dev
```

- Download libfilezilla from https://lib.filezilla-project.org/download.php
- Unpack and cd to directory

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

- Download cryptodev from https://github.com/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux
- Unpack and cd to directory

```
make
sudo make install
```

- Download libgnutls from https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnutls/v3.4/
- Unpack and cd to directory

```
./configure --enable-fips140-mode --enable-cryptodev --enable-openssl-compatibility
make
sudo make install
```

- Download Filezilla source code from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1
- Unpack and cd to directory

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```